# Why does jquery function .hide flicker on page load before hiding

Tags: jquery

I'm learning query and i'm hiding a button if a classname exists, but when I load the page and the classname exists the button shows for s brief second before hiding, what am I doing wrong and is there a way I can speed it up?

Here's my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // If the imagelinks with classname clonedInput are shown, then hide the add image button
  if ( $(".clonedInput").length) {
      $('.add-logo-button').hide();
  }
  // When you click clone. hide the button
  $('.add-logo-button').click(function(){
      $(".add-logo-button").hide();
  });
  // When you click remove. show the button
  $('.remove-logo').click(function(){
      $(".add-logo-button").show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't using CSS (e.g. `display:none`) be easier?

Comment: There is no way to speed it up, it waits for DOM ready and in some browsers that will get you a flicker.

The solution is to set the element to initially being hidden, and reversing the condition, showing it with javascript, but if the user has disabled javascript the element will never be shown.

The other option would be to place a script tag right after the element in the DOM and dropping the DOM ready handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it first load it takes some moment to execute jquery to hide this element. for this moment until it executes jquery to hide it will showing in the page.

so you need to use css (e.g inline style `display:none` ) for this element what you are hiding in page load. if you inline css then it will executed in html loading and it will not show up for any moment.

Comment: Why does it have to be inline?

Comment: Thanks, added this and now it's fine.

Comment: @j08691: actually it needs css to hide it

Comment: I know CSS is the solution, my question to you is why do you say it has to be inline?

Comment: I'm interested to know too?